# Подсветка строк и столбцов в таблице

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть таблица.

```
<table>
    <tr><td /><td /><td /></tr>
    <tr><td /><td /><td /></tr>
    <tr><td /><td /><td /></tr>
</table>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при наведении указателем мыши на одну из клеток таблицы, подсвечивались другим цветом столбец и строка, в пересечении которых находится клетка.

Если пользоваться стилями CSS, то подсвечиваются только строка и сама клетка (то есть столбец, состоящий из одной клетки).

Как это сделать наиболее просто из JavaScript/JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, устанавливать дополнительный класс на столбец и строку при наведении мыши на ячейку.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <colgroup />
    <colgroup />
    <colgroup />
    ...
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.hover {
    ...
}
```

JQuery:

```
// Подсвечивать столбцы и строки при наведении мыши в перекрестье
$('table').delegate('td.input', 'mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover', e.type == 'mouseover');
    $('colgroup').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('hover', e.type == 'mouseover');
});
```